# Null reference on foreach loop in Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

EDIT: removing the `@page` annotation in the Index.cshtml fixed the problem.

When calling the page I am getting a error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at AspNetCore.Views_Inspector_Inspect.get_Model()

Which is caused by this line: `@foreach (var rule in Model.Items)`
Surely enough, when debugging, I see that `Model` is indeed null.

But I call this view using the desired object like so: `return View(res);`

Furthermore, getting model data using DisplayTextFor like so: `<h2>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.CardNumber)</h2>` indeed works and displays the correct data.

What am I doing wrong here?

Full code below.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Inspect() {
    var res = GetDataObject();
    return View(res);
}
```

Inspect.cshtml:

```
@page
@model mynamespace.DataObject

<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;    
    }
</style>

<h2>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.SomeItem)</h2> <!-- THIS WORKS -->


    <table class="table" style="width: 50%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var rule in Model.SomeCollection) <!-- Model is null -->
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => rule.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => rule.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => rule.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => rule.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => rule.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Model` is `null` and not `SomeCollection` is `null`?

Comment: Using Razer Pages `@page` is not meant to be used with controllers, remove that. Razer Pages stand on their own, and if you want to display a page through a Controller use Views.

Comment: did you try debug and the value in "res" before rendering view?

Comment: @HenkMollema yes i am sure. i debugged it and Model itself is null

Comment: @AntonToshik not quite understand what you mean. the html is in the Views folder and apart from the foreach loop it works.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI yes i did debug before returning the view, both `res` and `SomeCollection` both have values and are not null

Comment: @AntonToshik removing the `@page` annotation actually fixed it and now its working.. can you explain why?

Comment: double check that if your model "mynamespace.DataObject" is compatible with "res" being sent from controller otherwise it will be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment.

The solution to this problem is removing the `@page` keyword.

What `@page` does is specifies that it's a Razor Page.

Your confusion is that you think that Razor Page is the same as Razor Syntax.

The .cshtml file extensions specifies the the file can have Razor Syntax, it doesn't mean it's a Razor Page.

MVC and Razor Pages follow a different naming convention, are setup differently in the Startup.cs file and will use different folder structure.

For example a `Index.cshtml` razor page will get it's model from `Index.cshtml.cs` file method `Get()` which will return a `Page(model)`.

The error occurs because the razor page doesn't expect anything from a controller, it's not meant to be served by one.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using Razor Pages, leave @page at the top and return IActionResult.

```
    public IActionResult OnGet(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
        return Page();
    }
```

Notice the return type is IActionResult, but the actual return is of type Page(). Behind the scenes, the page is returned with the model bound. It appears to be equivalent to:

```
return MyPage(this);
```